# Looping through the inconsistent parent object with Cypress

Tags: html, cypress

I am writing automated test case with Cypress.

I need to loop through all children of the element and verify its data. The problem is that all the children are object with `<a>` tags and `href` value attribute except for the first one.

The first one is wrapped into a `span` creating the following hierarchy:
`parent -> span -> a with href value`.

How to organize a loop?

I tried to remove the span element but it is removed with a child `<a>` inside

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, here is what can help you.

First, you define whether a current child is a span, if it is you are looking for its child inside a span element and working with found . If it is not a span, do the logic you need:

```
    cy.wrap(option)
      .children()
      .each(($child, index) => {
        if ($child.is('span')) {
         // Get an <a> element inside <span>
          const linkedinLink = $child.find('a');
          // Do any other logic
          return;
        } else if ($child.is('a')) {
          //Process all children except for the first one
          cy.wrap($child).should('have.attr', 'href', value);
          // Do any other logic
        } else {
          cy.log('Unexpected element type:', $child.prop('tagName'));
        }
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 5):

If you switch from `.children()` to `.find()` the query will return any child or grandchild and skip the `span` that is different for the first item.

The `.find()` command looks any number of levels down the HTML tree, whereas
`.children()` only takes the first level descendants.

The result is a lot simpler, no need to do any `if() else()` construct and you can focus on verifying the data.

```js
cy.get(parent)
  .find('a')    // pick up parent->a as well as parent->span->a
  .each($a => {
    // ...verify its data
  })
```

---

By the way - ***I tried to remove the span element*** - generally you don't want to alter the page during a test, because there might be side effects to doing so that make your test different to the user experience.